# BigQueryCheckAsyncOperator in airflow does not exist

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to use async operators for bigquery; however,

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryCheckAsyncOperator
```

gives the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BigQueryCheckOperatorAsync' from 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery'
```

The documentation in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html mentions that `BigQueryCheckAsyncOperator` exists.

I am using airflow 2.4.

How to import it?

Comment: I am not sure if it's relevant, the error message gives a different import name BigQueryCheckOperatorAsync instead of BigQueryCheckAsyncOperator? is the first snippet the import line from your code? (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you are trying to import was never released.
It was added in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26156) and removed in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26433) both were part of Google provider 8.4.0 release thus overall the `BigQueryCheckAsyncOperator` class was never part of the release.

You can use defer mode in the existed class `BigQueryCheckOperator` by setting the [`deferrable`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/199359bb3886699904ca075de7bd5fdfe5105c5f/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery.py#L190) parameter to `True`.

Comment: Thank you, airflow documentation needs improvement; anyway eventually I found it: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryCheckOperator